# Making a program that lists files in a directory and sorts the output

Tags: c, sorting, malloc, ls

I use `opendir(.)` to open a path to the directory I want to read from. I then use `readdir` with a loop to go through all the files and directories in the current directory. I then have a `char**` list to store the contents of readdir. I then do a sort on `**list` to put in lexigraphic order. I keep getting an overflow error when sorting output only when I have a file with a length of over 63 chars. Why is that and how can I fix it?

```
void ls_short() {
    char **list = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    DIR  *dir;
    struct dirent *rd;
    dir = opendir(".");
    // check to make sure that we can open the directory
    if(dir == NULL){
        perror("Not able to open The current directory.");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    while((rd = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        list = realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(*list));
        list[count] = rd ->d_name;
        ++count;
        printf("%s\n",rd ->d_name);
    }
    printf("here we will print the list\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < count;i++){
        printf("%s\n",list[i]);
    }
    printf("Now we print the list in order and also get rid of . and .. directory\n");
    list = realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(*list));
    list[count] = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < count - 1; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j < count - i - 1; j++){
            if (strcasecmp(list[j], list[j + 1]) > 0) {
                    char* temp;
                    temp = (char*)calloc(count, sizeof(char)*256);
                    strcpy(temp, list[j]);
                    strcpy(list[j], list[j + 1]);
                    strcpy(list[j + 1], temp);
                    free(temp);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 2; i < count;i++){
        printf("%s\n",list[i]);
    }
    closedir(dir);
}
```

This is the error I am getting:

[image: screenshot of error messages]

```
=================================================================
==43335==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap: memory ranges [0x6250000001fd,0x625000000220) and [0x62500000021d, 0x625000000240) overlap
    #0 0x103ef03ef in wrap_strcpy+0xaf (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x433ef)
    #1 0x103e9aa5d in ls_short ls.c:61
    #2 0x103e9a5c4 in main ls.c:16
    #3 0x7fff20379620 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

0x6250000001fd is located 253 bytes inside of 8192-byte region [0x625000000100,0x625000002100)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x103ef54c0 in wrap_malloc+0xa0 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x484c0)
    #1 0x7fff2025b0fe in _readdir_unlocked$INODE64+0x6d (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x2a0fe)
    #2 0x7fff2025b227 in readdir$INODE64+0x22 (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x2a227)
    #3 0x103e9a6ad in ls_short ls.c:42
    #4 0x103e9a5c4 in main ls.c:16
    #5 0x7fff20379620 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

0x62500000021d is located 285 bytes inside of 8192-byte region [0x625000000100,0x625000002100)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x103ef54c0 in wrap_malloc+0xa0 (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x484c0)
    #1 0x7fff2025b0fe in _readdir_unlocked$INODE64+0x6d (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x2a0fe)
    #2 0x7fff2025b227 in readdir$INODE64+0x22 (libsystem_c.dylib:x86_64+0x2a227)
    #3 0x103e9a6ad in ls_short ls.c:42
    #4 0x103e9a5c4 in main ls.c:16
    #5 0x7fff20379620 in start+0x0 (libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x15620)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: strcpy-param-overlap (libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x433ef) in wrap_strcpy+0xaf
==43335==ABORTING
Abort trap: 6
```

Comment: Please post the error as plain text, not a screenshot.

Comment: Any reason why you're hand-rolling a bubble sort vs. just using `qsort`?

Comment: @Barmar I posted the error in text format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`readdir()` has a static buffer for `rd->d_name`, which it reuses each time you call it, so all your `list` elements are pointing to the same string.

You should make a copy of the strings when you assign them to the array.

```
list[count] = strdup(rd->d_name);
```

And when you're sorting, don't copy the names between strings, just swap the pointers.

```
            if (strcasecmp(list[j], list[j + 1]) > 0) {
                char* temp;
                temp = list[j];
                list[j] = list[j+1];
                list[j+1] = temp;
            }
```

Comment: That won't work. It only allocates enough memory for *this* file name. But his design requires each string buffer be large enough to hold the largest file name. (Look at code like `strcpy(list[j], list[j + 1]);`.)

Comment: Good catch. I added how to do it by swapping pointers instead of copying strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while((rd = readdir(dir)) != NULL){
        list = realloc(list, (count+1)*sizeof(*list));
        list[count] = rd ->d_name;
        ++count;
        printf("%s\n",rd ->d_name);
    }
```

Nowhere do you allocate memory to hold the string you're adding to the list. You allocate memory to hold a pointer to it, but that's it.

You need to change `list[count] = rd ->d_name;` to something like:

```
    list[count] = malloc(256);
    strcpy(list[count], rd->d_name);
```

Also, you don't need to allocate new memory for strings when you sort. If you already have memory allocated for every string you need to store (which you must or your list is already broken), why would changing the order require allocating new memory to hold the strings?

Comment: Those two lines of code fixed the issue. I'm just curious why the program seemed to work fine until the length of the file name became longer than 63 and also why do I have to use strcpy ?  also with regards to allocating new memory for the sort are you referring to temp or list? Thank you for your help.